# Creating a trigger that will notify user from application?

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I have a trigger that I would like to notify the user without stopping him/her from proceeding.
This is what I currently have.
I have tried many different type of SQLstates but none have seemed to do this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEAD_SAT
BEFORE UPDATE OF TRAILER ON TRIP
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE DEAD_SAT VARCHAR(10);

SET DEAD_SAT = COALESCE((SELECT TRAILER_ID FROM TRAILER WHERE LAST_SAT_DATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 8 DAYS AND N.TRAILER = TRAILER_ID),'NO');


     IF DEAD_SAT <> 'NO' AND USER NOT IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD. PLEASE GET IT REPLACED.';
     CALL SYSIBMINTERNAL.SQLEML_RAISE_ERROR(438, 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD. PLEASE GET IT REPLACED.', NULL);
END IF;
END
```

[image: I would like to have an option to proceed beyond here]

Comment: Trigger is unable to "notify user" or anything else, because it runs deep in the bowels of the database server. All it can do is throw an exception to the calling application, and it is the application responsibility to handle that exception as it pleases. I think it's the third question you ask on the topic, but I'm afraid the answer will still be the same.

Comment: haha you caught me im desperate man

Comment: What is your front-end?

Comment: ...and is there a middle-ware tier?

Comment: I'm with mustaccio - you're trying to do this in the wrong place.  A trigger should either be used for completing a record, or rejecting it.  You could have the trigger dump a line into a "notification" table pretty easily, but I wouldn't bother: you'd have to read that table, so you just might as read this one for the error condition.  Oh, your statement reads a little wonky - I'd grab the last time and compare that, rather than the `COALESCE()`/want null bit you currently have.

Comment: Recommended course of action: post a question on your **higher-level requirement**, not your attempts to solve it.  What you need is help on how to design the solution to this.  A question would be like "I need to warn users of a potential problem for reason X, with these specific requirements: Y.  My system architecture is Z.  I have tried a trigger, and some other things, but they don't meet my needs (give reasons it didn't work and link to any previous relevant questions)".

Comment: Further reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem